# PHP/MySQL Query returns results not in database

Tags: php, mysql, email, session

I'm trying to create a page that checks it you're login information in correct. For some reason, when I echo the results query that selects the data from the database, I don't get the data I should from the database, I'm not sure what data it is. Here's what shows on the page:

```
Connected successfully
Resource id #3
```

Here's my php code:

```
<?php
//start session
session_start();

//connect to MySQL Database
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
if (!$con) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully<br />'; 

// make members the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('members_db', $con);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use members database : ' . mysql_error());
}


$email = $_SESSION['email'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT email,password FROM `members` WHERE 'email' = '$email'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($email == $row[0] && $_SESSION['password'] == $row[1])
{
    $_SESSION['loggedin']="YES";
    $url= "Location: welcome.php";
    header($url);
    exit;
}

echo $result;

/*
//Problems:
$problem = "";
if ($email == $row[0] && $_SESSION['password'] != $row[1])
{
    $problem = "invalidPassword";
}
if ($email != $row[0])
{
    $problem = "InvalidUser";
}
$url = "Location: index.php?problem=$problem";
header($url);
exit;*/
?>
```

Comment: mysql_query returns a resource, so that's what you get when you echo it. you should be looking at what's in `$row` which will tell you why your if failed

Comment: Obligatory `mysql` is depreciated use `mysqli`

Comment: Try `echo $row[0]; echo $row[1]` after `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);` . Also make sure your query is returning a row . You can use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to find how many rows are returned .

Answer (score 0):

Here if this helps to check if you are getting the right data, it doesn't look like you are even getting into the right area where the user is validated

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
 if ($email == $row[0] && $_SESSION['password'] == $row[1])
 {

 $_SESSION['loggedin']="YES";
 $url= "Location: welcome.php";
 header($url);
 exit;
}
else //Validation failed
{

echo $row[0] . ' SESSION EMAIL ' . $email; //Which would echo the email that was returned and the email stored in the session, if they do not match it means the password was wrong.
}
```